Is travel insurance required for an hour stopover in Paris, France
I am an Indian citizen (Indian Passport) who is travelling from Detroit, US to Mumbai, India with an stopover in Paris, France. I have 1 hr 10 min stopover in Paris. Is there a requirement to have travel insurance for the stopover in Paris i.e. will immigration in Paris ask for it?

Do you have a Schengen visa? Do you have a valid US visa or document? Did you book the single ticket with a single itinerary/ticket number?

I do not have Schengen visa. I have Advance Parole which allows me to go in and out of US. I also have valid Canadian Visa stamped on my passport. Yes, single ticket with single itinerary/ticket number.

You are not immigrating. You are transiting. Immigration implies entering the country.

Note: it is not travel insurance but health insurance (so to get health costs covered). On some countries a travel insurance cover boths, but e.g. in Europe (with health mandatory insurance, with some limitation e.g. geographically, we tend to interpret travel insurance as the insurance about delays, cancellations, lost baggage, etc. -- just to clarify, because if you google, you may find contradictory informations: but it is just different usage of travel insurance

@GiacomoCatenazzi A typical European travel insurance policy will also cover medical costs abroad, as regular health insurance does not always cover that (or not at their actual costs). But obviously you're right that coverage for all the other risks (delay, luggage theft, etc.) is not mandatory. On the other hand, “health insurance” is just as misleading as it could suggest you have to show you have some sort of health insurance in your country of residence, which is not mandatory either. To avoid the confusion, the Schengen Visa code actually uses the phrase “travel medical insurance”.


Is there a requirement to have travel insurance for the stopover in Paris i.e. will immigration in Paris ask for it?

No.
A) you will not pass through immigration since you are not entering the Schengen area. B) Immigration is almost never concerned with Travel Insurance. In rare circumstances you may have to show proof of some sort of insurance (mostly health insurance) but that's not going to apply to an Indian citizen traveling to India.
This being said, 1:10 is VERY tight. You WILL have to clear security in Paris and can take a long time. I recommend familiarizing yourself with the layout of the airport and the gates: CDG is difficult to navigate. I suggest asking a separate question with your exact flight details to get some advise on how to make this. Currently, the normal layover time for DTW->CDG->BOM is 2:40 so something is unusual about your itinerary.

Thanks so much. My flight is AF377 9:00 pm Detroit to 9:50 am Paris and then AF218 10:55 am Paris to 00:05 am Mumbai. I am flying business class so hopefully can avail separate security line - purple “Accès N°1” lanes

Are both flights on a single PNR? If so, was the ticket purchased directly from Air France?

Both flights have single PNR though tickets were purchased through Priceline

“Travel insurance” can cover many different risks, what's required to apply for a Schengen visa is officially called “travel medical insurance”.

... strongly recommend switching to an earlier flight: these days DL228 arrives 08:25.  If there's even the slightest delay with AF377, the security lines won't matter.

Travel (medical) insurance is a requirement to obtain a full Schengen visa but it's not a requirement for entry for people who do not need a visa (it is not mentioned in article 6 of the Schengen Borders code) or for airport transit visa (see article 15 of the Schengen Visa code). Your question therefore reduces to “Do I need a visa for this transit?” and the rules can be summarized easily:

If you don't need a visa for transit, travel medical insurance is not mandatory
If you need an airport transit visa, travel medical insurance is not required and you should not be asked to prove you have it when applying for the visa
If you need a full Schengen visa (“uniform visa”), travel medical insurance is required and you will be asked to present proof when applying for the visa

In any case, if it is legally required, it will come up during the visa application. Since you have determined that you don't need a visa for this trip, you don't require proof of insurance either.

Thanks so much. From https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/airport-transit-visa website, it seems like I dont need airport transit visa if I have valid Canadian visa stamped on my passport which I have (I also have Advance Parole card from US though technically its not a visa I think). Excerpts here - "A holder of a valid visa for a Member State of the European Union or the European Economic Area, Canada, the United States or Japan, regardless of the airport of departure and regardless of the airport of arrival located outside the Schengen Area"

@VohraSingh Yes, this sounds correct but I didn't take the time to go through the rules again. In any case, if you don't need a visa, know you're fine regarding insurance. This is actually the one point where the requirements for entry and the requirements to get a visa differ.
